# Source of shabbat evening kiddush text?

Tags: shabbat, sources-mekorot, kiddush, nuschaot, evening-night

The beginning of the shabbat evening kiddush (*vayehi erev, vayehi boker, yom hashishi...*) is from [Bereshit, 1:31 ff](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0101.htm#31). Where does the second part (*khi hu yom tehilah lemikraei kodesh...*) come from? Is it also from the Torah?

Comment: Igor, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks very much for bringing your question here! Please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Did you mean specifically the part starting "_ki hu yom t'chila l'mikrae kodesh_"? There is stuff before that but after the quotation from Genesis.

Answer (score 8):

Avudraham cites the following verses for a couple of the lines:

- "*ki vanu vacharta*" from [*D'varim* 7:7](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%96_%D7%96)
- "*v'osanu kidashta mikol ha'amim*" from [*D'varim* 26:19](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%9B%D7%95_%D7%99%D7%98)

He also gives these non-citation explanations of the sources of the ideas:

- "*t'chila l'mikra'ei kodesh*" due to the fact that *shabas* is listed first among the holidays (in [*Vayikra* 23](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%9B%D7%92/%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%93))
- "*zecher liy'tzi'as Mitzrayim*" based on a [couple places in] Ramba"n's commentary on the Torah where he says that *shabas* attests to the miracle of the Exodus

Comment: So it's not a direct quote from Tanach, but only inspired by it? Do we know who wrote (or compiled?) the kiddush?

Comment: It's either shabbat (sphardi pronunciation) or shabbos (ashkenazi)... sorry, just a pet peeve of mine

Comment: @AriA I hold of this orthography because in English we do not verbalize gemination so the second "b" is extraneous in spelling and the vowel quality of _kamatz_ and _patach_ (for Ashkenazim, as interpreted by me) is different but not as different as "a" from "o" in [my pronunciation of] English in most contexts, while both are within the range of possible "a"s in [my pronunciation of] English. It would be nice to distinguish them but the poverty of the literon makes this the choice on which _akpid_.

Comment: . . . "Avudraham", on the other hand, I don't claim to have any idea about.

Answer (score 6):

The first paragraph of kiddush is Biblical verses. The second paragraph is part of the core text of prayers, which were presumably finalized by *Anshei Knesset HaGedolah*, "The Men of the Great Assembly", i.e. the rabbinic leaders during the early Second Temple period, about 2300 years ago. (See [Rambam Berachot 1:5](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/i/25.htm))

The same goes for something like the *Amida* prayer on shabbat. The paragraphs *yismach moshe* and *elokeinu veilokei avoteinu, retzei vimnuchateinu* were composed by the editors of the core siddur 2300 years ago, while it also contains a paragraph of Bible -- "as it says in the Torah ... *veshamru bnei yisrael et hashabat* ..."

As referenced in the other answer, it's clear that when the Men of Great Assembly composed the core siddur, they often used Biblical paraphrases and references. But it's not "this whole paragraph comes right out of the Bible."